# RDP to windows failing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp

I have fresh Windows 2016 running, when I try to **RDP** from Windows 10 I get this error

[image: CredSSP oracle error]

What patch I need to install on the Windows & Mac clients to fix this issue ?

Comment: See these links?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4295591/credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation-error-when-to-rdp-to-azure-vm https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/unable-to-rdp-to-virtual-machine-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/

Answer (score 3):

> I have fresh Windows 2016,

You need to apply patches on the server that you just freshly installed.  Not your clients.  Fire off Windows update on the server and let those updates apply.

All your servers and clients will need one of the cumulative monthly updates from after May 2018, ideally all your systems would have an update to something for the last month.

Comment: Whats need to be done on client on Mac ?

Comment: Not entirely certain, but my guess would that you need to make sure you have the latest version downloaded from the app store.